# how to put a checkbox with headings in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I am trying to create a multipage document that is basically a long, somewhat complicated checklist. I would like to use the usual headings but would like a 'checkable item / marker' put in front of most headings.  I'd like the doc to look like this:

... a random excerpt...

<> 2.4.1 Purchase fresh ingredients
       blah blah

<> 2.4.1.1 Buy tomatoes
       blah be sure they are fresh

<> 2.4.1.2 Buy onions
       blah but not moldy ones
... etc ...

In other words I would like each heading / subheading /subsubheading to have a checkbox in front of the heading, followed by the heading number and then the heading text.

[I know I could do this by hand - but using the automatic heading numbering facility to generate the numbers would save a lot of work (esp. considering the doc will probably be edited numerous times.]

Any ideas on how to get something that looks like a checkbox in front of the automatic numbering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To have a character or symbol automatically generated *in front* of automatic level numbering...for example:

 2.4.1  Purchase fresh ingredients blah blah

 2.4.1.1  Buy tomatoes blah be sure they are fresh

---

2. Open `Define New Multilevel List` dialog box.  (You can do this by pulling down the menu from the <kbd>Multilevel List</kbd> button on the home tab.)
3. In the `Define new Multilevel list` dialog box, click the level you would like to modify.
4. In the `Enter Formatting For Number:`fill-in box, paste the character(s) or symbol(s) in front of the automatic level number (denoted by gray highlight).

   After you do this you should see both the inserted hard character (not highlighted) and the automatic level number (gray highlighted) in this fill-in box.
5. Repeat for each level that you wish a box (or other) character to appear in front of the number.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Your automatically numbered levels should automatically generate the character(s) that were formatted in the `Define New Multilevel List` dialog box.

Comment: I am only able to select a single font, so you have to find a font that has both numbers and a box character?

Answer (score 1):

To do this try the following steps:

1. Right click the heading you want to change (say `Heading 1`) and click `Modify`.
2. At the bottom there is a <kbd>Format</kbd> button, click that and select `Numbering`.
3. In the Window that pops up select the `Bullet` tab at the top.
4. If any of the preset bullets work for you then you're good to go, skip to step 7 in that case, otherwise select <kbd>Define New Bullet</kbd>
5. In the new window that pops up select <kbd>Symbol</kbd>, this will show the character selection window.
6. Find a square box character you can use.  I found a reasonable one at `25A1` (you can probably type `25A1` into the `Character code:` box).  Otherwise browse around to find a symbol you like.
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> until you are back at the page you are working on.
8. Select the text you want and click your updated heading in the style list.

For me after doing this I get:

[image]

Which seems to fit your requirements quite well.

Comment: This is pretty neat trick. I gotta remember that.